# finding the position of an element from a list of list

Tags: list, haskell

I want to find the position of an element from a list of list.

FOr example , in a given list [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] I want to find the position of 8.The function should return [[3,2]],namely third row and second column.
if the list is [[1,2,8],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
then it should return:
[[1,3],[3,2]]
if it can not find then it should return empty list

```
findPosition :: [[Int]]  ->  [(Int,Int)]
findPostion  ..  ?
```

I want to do it with most effective way.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you only need the first occurence? E.g. what should be returned when [[1,2],[1,3]] is given and you want the position of 1?

Comment: no i want all occurrences of 1 . IN your example it should return [[1,1],[2,1]] . I edited the text the return type should be list of list too.

Comment: We still need more info.  What should it return if the number does not occur at all?  What have you tried so far?  Show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Data.List

findPosition  :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [(Int,Int)]
findPosition n xs = fp n xs 0

fp n [] i = []
fp n (x:xs) i = p x ++ fp n xs (i+1)
    where 
      p x = zip (repeat i) (elemIndices n x)
```

Example:

```
findPosition 3 [[2,3,4,3],[4,5,2,3],[],[3,2,5,6,3],[2],[3]]
   == [(0,1),(0,3),(1,3),(3,0),(3,4),(5,0)]
```

If you change the function's type signature to:

```
findPosition :: (Eq a1, Num a) => a1 -> [[a1]] -> [(a, Int)]
```

you will have a more general solution. Example:

```
findPosition 'a' ["car","small","caveat","big","","aah!"]
   == [(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,4),(5,0),(5,1)]
```

Comment: Also: `zipWith (,) = zip`.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so let's break this down.

If you're only interested in a normal list of ints, you've got

```
 findPosition :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

How can you implement that? Well, uh, you need an input for the thing you're actually searching for!

```
 findPosition :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

OK, cool. So the built-in `elem` function tells you *if* the element you want is there. But we want it's *position*. So how? Well, you can "label" every element with it's position, like so:

```
 label :: [x] -> [(Int, x)]
 label = zip [0..]
```

Now we can use `filter` to find all the items:

```
 find :: (Eq x) => x -> [(Int, x)] -> [(Int, x)]
 find x0 = filter (\ (n, x) -> x == x0)
```

But we only want the actual positions, not the `x`s (which are all identical at this point). So we can `map fst` to get that.

Assembling it all,

```
 findPosition :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
 findPosition x0 = map fst . filter (\ (n, x) -> x == x0) . zip [0..]
```

---

That's great! But you wanted a list *of lists* of ints, right?

I would suggest you change your requirement spec to return each "coordinate" as a tuple rather than a list. That is, make it so

```
findPosition 8 [[1,2,8],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] => [(1, 3), (3, 2)]
```

It's probably less confusing that way. Hopefully I've given you enough hints to figure things out from here...

Comment: Check this pls:  findPosition :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
 findPosition x0 = map fst . filter (\ (n, x) -> x == x0) . zip [0..] The function does take only one argument but you define two. It cant compile

Comment: In this case the second argument can be omitted, because the result of composing the functions via (.) is itself a function that takes a single parameter. Another example would be 'add x y = x + y' which is the same as 'add x= (+) x' or 'add x = (x +)'

Answer (score 4):

Your type signature is wrong. It should be

```
findPosition :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [(Int, Int)]
```

because

- you need to tell the function what value to look for
- there's no reason to restrict `findPosition` to only searching lists of lists of `Int`s --- all it needs to do with the inner elements is compare them for equality
- your version would return a list of lists that were always of length two: if an inner list was empty or had length three, that would be a bug; we can exclude the possibility of that sort of bug by using a pair instead

I would also have `findPosition` result in zero-based indices (as used by Haskell's standard list functions) instead of the one-based indices you asked for.

So I will have e.g. `findPosition 8 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] = [(2, 1)]`.

---

Sadly Hoogle knows of no functions with type `Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [(Int, Int)]`. But a search for the simpler signature [`Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq%20a%20=%3E%20a%20-%3E%20%5ba%5d%20-%3E%20%5bInt%5d) (a similar function that searches a list instead of a list of lists) points us at [`elemIndices`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aelemIndices). We can use this in `findPosition`.

(Oh, I'm too tired to finish this. Hopefully it'll give you food for thought.)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
import Control.Monad

findPosition :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [(Int,Int)]
findPosition e ll = do
    let annotate = zip [1..]
    (i1,x) <- annotate ll
    (i2,y) <- annotate x
    guard $ y == e
    return (i1,i2)
```

We annotate each element in the list and sublists with an index, and use the Monad instance for List to search all possible ocurrences.

Comment: `zipWith (,)` rather than `zip` because...?

Comment: Ouch, you are right. The zipWith is unnecessary. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: did you try it with example input output? THis code cant compile

Comment: I did try it. Maybe the problem is that I omitted the "import Control.Monad"?

Comment: It gives the error : No instance for (Show ([[[[t0]]]] -> [(Int, Int)]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show ([[[[t0]]]] -> [(Int, Int)]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: Look at the signature of the function. You have to pass the element you search for as the first argument. Like this:   findPosition 1 [[2,3],[3,3,1],[1,1]]

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete It's no biggie... Just a single raised eyebrow. ;-)